# How do I create a bitmap using the BITMAPV5HEADER header?

Tags: c++, bmp

This is my current code, but it causes an error when casting to BITMAPINFOHEADER:

```
/* Create the bitmap */
BITMAPINFO bmpinfo;
ZeroMemory(&bmpinfo, sizeof(bmpinfo));
BITMAPV5HEADER bmpheader;
ZeroMemory(&bmpheader, sizeof(bmpheader));
bmpheader.bV5Size = sizeof(BITMAPV5HEADER);
bmpheader.bV5Width = width;
bmpheader.bV5Height = height;
bmpheader.bV5Planes = 1;
bmpheader.bV5BitCount = 32;
bmpheader.bV5Compression = BI_BITFIELDS;
bmpheader.bV5SizeImage = width*height*4;
bmpheader.bV5RedMask = 0x00FF0000;
bmpheader.bV5GreenMask = 0x0000FF00;
bmpheader.bV5BlueMask = 0x000000FF;
bmpheader.bV5AlphaMask = 0xFF000000;
bmpheader.bV5CSType = 0x57696e20; // LCS_WINDOWS_COLOR_SPACE
bmpheader.bV5Intent = LCS_GM_BUSINESS;
bmpinfo.bmiHeader = reinterpret_cast<BITMAPINFOHEADER>(bmpheader);
void* converted = NULL;
HDC screen = GetDC(NULL);
HBITMAP result = CreateDIBSection(screen, &bmpinfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &converted, NULL, 0);
ReleaseDC(NULL, screen);
// Image data filled here
```

How will I be able to do this successfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BITMAPINFO` isn't a true structure, it's more just documentation about how the color map follows the header. Just pass your `BITMAPV5HEADER` directly to CreateDIBSection:

```
HBITMAP result = CreateDIBSection(screen, reinterpret_cast<BITMAPINFO *>(&bmpheader), DIB_RGB_COLORS, &converted, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: @Mark Ransom: I found `BITMAPV5HEADER` and thought about just passing it to `CreateDIBSection`, assuming that it can infer the kind of structure by looking at `bV5Size`, but I could not find any documentation on it. Do you possibly have a link?