# Windows bitmaps: BITMAPV5HEADER and BITMAPINFO compatible?

Tags: windows, winapi, bitmap, gdi, createdibsection

From [the documentation on `CreateDIBSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd183494(v=vs.85).aspx) I observe that `CreateDIBSection` takes a pointer to a `BITMAPINFO` as the second parameter.

However, I came across various places indicating that it might be allowed to pass pointers to other structures (in particular `BITMAPV5HEADER`), including

- [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4455762/255688)
- [Chromium source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/ui/gfx/icon_util.cc?q=createdibsection&sq=package:chromium&l=186&dr=C)

I have a feeling that this makes perfect sense (`BITMAPV5HEADER` can be seen as an "extended version" of `BITMAPINFO` wrt struct layout), but I could not find a single piece of official documentation on this topic.

Can anybody confirm that passing a `BITMAPV5HEADER*` instead of a `BITMAPINFO` is actually valid and possibly offer some documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer has to be *no*. `BITMAPV5HEADER*` is not a substitute for `BITMAPINFO*` and may not be passed whenever `BITMAPINFO*` is expected (simply because `BITMAPINFO` contains palette colors after the header, and `BITMAPV5HEADER` is just a header).

---

It is certainly fine to pass `BITMAPV5HEADER*` instead of `BITMAPINFO*` provided that the `BITMAPV5HEADER` is a part of `BITMAPINFO` and has required kind of palette color data after it. That is documented, although kind of indirectly, through use instructions and common sense:

- `BITMAPV5HEADER` is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183381(v=vs.85).aspx) to be an "extended version of th `BITMAPINFOHEADER` structure", so that part is clear.
- `BITMAPINFO` is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183375(v=vs.85).aspx) to combine a header and color data. The header is included by value as opposed to by pointer, so at this point it's clear the header may not just grow in size as it pleases, otherwise it would be impossible to access `BITMAPINFO.bmiColors` and the whole idea of having an extended version of the header would be pointless.
- And that problem is then resolved in [another place in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx) ("Remarks" section):

  > An application should use the information stored in the `biSize` member to locate the color table in a `BITMAPINFO` structure, as follows:
  >
  > ```
  > pColor = ((LPSTR)pBitmapInfo + (WORD)(pBitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biSize));
  > ```

Although I believe this part was not confusing for you to begin with.

---

Now for the long answer.

There *appear* to be *two* cases when `BITMAPV5HEADER*` can be passed for `BITMAPINFO*`. Neither of the two is documented in a concrete way, and if for the first one we can apply same common sense we applied above, the second one appears to be a bug in the documentation:

- When `BITMAPINFO.bmiColors` is documented to be `NULL`. You can find the complete list of such cases in the [documentation for `BITMAPINFOHEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx).
- When the header is `BITMAPV4HEADER` or `BITMAPV5HEADER`, the bitmap has 16 or 32 bit colors, and compression is set to `BI_BITFIELDS`. In that case the color masks that are documented to follow the header are instead taken from the respective dedicated fields of the headers, and the three `DWORD`s that follow the header are ignored.

  This is easy to prove by slightly modifying the [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4455655/11683):

  ```
  typedef struct tagV5BMPINFO {
      BITMAPV5HEADER bmiHeader;
      DWORD        bmiColors[3];
  } V5BMPINFO;

  int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
  {
      V5BMPINFO bmpinfo = { 0 };
      BITMAPV5HEADER bmpheader = { 0 };

      bmpheader.bV5Size = sizeof(BITMAPV5HEADER);
      bmpheader.bV5Width = width;
      bmpheader.bV5Height = height;
      bmpheader.bV5Planes = 1;
      bmpheader.bV5BitCount = 32;
      bmpheader.bV5Compression = BI_BITFIELDS;
      bmpheader.bV5SizeImage = 400*200*4;
      bmpheader.bV5RedMask   = 0x00FF0000;
      bmpheader.bV5GreenMask = 0x0000FF00;
      bmpheader.bV5BlueMask  = 0x000000FF;
      bmpheader.bV5AlphaMask = 0xFF000000;
      bmpheader.bV5CSType = 0x57696e20; // LCS_WINDOWS_COLOR_SPACE
      bmpheader.bV5Intent = LCS_GM_BUSINESS;

      bmpinfo.bmiHeader = bmpheader;
      // Put them in reverse order here compared to the above
      bmpinfo.bmiColors[0] = 0x000000FF;
      bmpinfo.bmiColors[1] = 0x0000FF00;
      bmpinfo.bmiColors[2] = 0x00FF0000;

      void* converted = NULL;
      HDC screen = GetDC(NULL);
      HBITMAP result = CreateDIBSection(screen, reinterpret_cast<BITMAPINFO*>(&bmpinfo), DIB_RGB_COLORS, &converted, NULL, 0);
      ReleaseDC(NULL, screen);


      DIBSECTION actual_data;
      GetObject(result, sizeof(actual_data), &actual_data);

      std::cout << std::hex;
      std::cout << actual_data.dsBitfields[0] << std::endl;
      std::cout << actual_data.dsBitfields[1] << std::endl;
      std::cout << actual_data.dsBitfields[2] << std::endl;
      std::cout << std::dec;

      DeleteObject(result);

      return 0;
  }
  ```

  Result:

  ```
  ff0000
  ff00
  ff
  ```

  *It would appear* the documentation was absentmindedly copied between `BITMAPINFOHEADER`, `BITMAPV4HEADER` and `BITMAPV5HEADER` when it should have been amended for the last two. The closest explanation I was able to find is [Bitmap Header Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183386(v=vs.85).aspx) that at least recognizes the existence of the dedicated mask fields, but still implies the values must be provided both in these fields and after the header in `bmiColors`:

  > The red, green, and blue bitfield masks for `BI_BITFIELD` bitmaps **immediately follow** the `BITMAPINFOHEADER`, **`BITMAPV4HEADER`, and `BITMAPV5HEADER`** structures. The `BITMAPV4HEADER` and `BITMAPV5HEADER` structures contain **additional** members for red, green, and blue masks as follows.

  (emphasis mine).

  We can only conclude from evidence that it is not true.
  It is less of documentation than I hoped.

Comment: @SGerg: I found your first point in the MSDN (even if the consequences are not entirely clear to me). Regarding point three: Is `pColor` the same as `bmiColors`? From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx I see that `BI_BITFIELDS` indicates `bmiColors` to be the color masks. If I now look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183381(v=vs.85).aspx, it tells me that `bV5RedMask`, `bV5GreenMask`, `bV5BlueMask` denote those color masks, and the offsets should correspond to `bmiColors`.

Comment: Continuing: Because of the same offset, I somehow suspected that I could just pass the whole `BITMAPV5HEADER*` instead of `BITMAPINFO*` and I assumed that basically `BITMAPV5HEADER` already "contains" the parts that would otherwise be contained in the `BITMAPINFO`'s `bmiColors`. Is this correct? Or do we have `bmiColors` *in addition* to those masks? One more thing: I found https://expertreplies.com/how-to-create-an-alpha-blended-cursor-or-icon-in-windows-xp/ (which seems to be taken from an old MSDN article), but I found nothing the like in the current MSDN.

Comment: @phimuemue [Like Mike Ransom said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4455762/11683), `BITMAPINFO` isn't a true structure. The `bmiColors` member is declared for technical reasons, but it may not be accessed directly by name. `pColor` is not the same as `bmiColors`, it's *the only* `bmiColors`, while `bmiColors` is not actually a thing. Neither `BITMAPV5HEADER` nor `BITMAPV4HEADER` include the `bmiColors` data, it must follow them so that `pColor` would still work. Consider what happens when the bitmap does *not* have `BI_BITFIELDS` - it would then not work if the masks were the same as `bmiColors`.

Comment: @SGerg Thanks a lot for your answer. But I do not see how - in Mike Ransom's answer - the `bmiColors` follow the `BITMAPV5HEADER` (he just passes the `BITMAPV5HEADER` a pointer without any clue about `bmiColors` whatsoever at call site). Is that then taken care of by `CreateDIBSection` then (basically meaning that `bmiColors` is actually only present in the generated bitmap)?

Comment: @phimuemue You are correct. For some reason I remembered that `BITMAPINFO` contains the image data which is not the case. I will rewrite/delete the answer.

Comment: @phimuemue I now have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155328/discussion-between-phimuemue-and-gserg).